# WordPress change search results

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I have got the problem that my WordPress theme ("Sydney") is displaying the search results wrong. Instead of just listing posts I want to display WooCommerce products only.

Those should be ordered in a nice grid as shown in this picture:

[image: this picture].

At the moment the results are listed like this

[image: like this].

How can I change the way the search results are displayed?

At the moment my `search.php` is looking like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-9">
    <main id="main" class="post-wrap" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'sydney' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h31>
        </h3>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', 'search' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Thank you guys a lot!

** **UPDATE**
The solution provided by kashalo partly worked, but search results still look slightly different from the product page and are listed in only one column instead of a grid.
[image: improvements by kashalo]

** **UPDATE**
The solution suggested by Alexander Wigmore looks almost the way I wanted it so look like. The only Problem with copying the `page.php`in the `search.php`is that the products are still getting displayed wheird, but not when they are displayed in the category they fit in. For example: When searching for *saat* the results are displaying the products at first with text only, but normaly under the *Saatgut* category.

[image: Alexander Wigmore's solution]

Comment: u need to alter the `content-search.php` not this this file which you post above

Comment: The Problem is that i haven't got full database access and the content-search.php is not displayed in the WordPress editor.

Comment: this file is not in the database it's in your theme director

Comment: dose your shop page have the same style like the pic above?

Comment: Yes, those screenshots are original screenshots of my shop.

Comment: change this line `get_template_part( 'content', 'search' );` to `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );` and let me know if you got the desired results

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your solution worked partly. I have added the results in the initial question.

Comment: am afraid no one can help u more this solution is actually not the best practice one but as you don't have access to your `content-search.php` which is wired because if you can access `search.php `then definilty  you can access the template file so try to look around :)

Comment: I will keep trying around with some code and then posting my final solution once I have found it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

my advise is not to directly modify the search file of wp or theme template but is a good practice to work with the child theme. For the design display of the result you can play a little with css to customize it as you want, instead for the results to show only the products you can use any filter builded on the theme you are using (if it have) or create yourself a function to filter the results (also called hooks).

An example for filtering results is like the above code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_woocommerce_products' ); // the hook

function filter_woocommerce_products( $query ) { // the function
    if( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // verify if can use the search function and the search string is from the search call
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' ); // filter the posts with type products that corrispond to woocommerce products.
    }
}
```

**and this function must be saved on the function.php file of your theme or the child theme.**

For more information i suggest you to read more about child theme and the pre_get_posts documentation on the wp page.

Hope it helps and feel free to ask.

Comment: I can also restrict the search results to products only in the "Ivory Search" plugin, but the problem of the way the results are displayed remains. To understand what I want the search results to look like and what they look like currently please see the pictures I added in my description.

Comment: I have seen the picture you included and normally that way is done by using specific template of the theme and it is styled with css. I suggest you to try to explore the css of the page you want to be like, to begin modify a little the look of the result page and than if you have any trouble you can share the code you are using to style. Just ask us to do it for you is not the purpose of SO. Hopeful you understand the point. Please take a look here for a fresh start: https://www.shift8web.ca/2016/03/customize-wordpress-search-results-page/

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't wanted to sound disrespectful in any way. My intention was not to ask you for detailed instructions, I rather wanted to know where to set the changes because I was unable to figure this out on my own. This might be related to me being new in web-development such as css, js and html. I'm just getting started and have basic knowledge. The reason why I have asked for help is because I was unable to find any solutions fitting my needs. If this intention does not fit the purpose of SO I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Absolutely no problem :) Looking a little to the official page of the Sydney page seems it doesnt have any specific template for products so in this case wp just take the default which is pretty poor. Looking to your code, the get_template_part function is taking none content to style the page so please change get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); to get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); to use the post format of your theme and please share the result. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion. I have tried your suggested changes, but this code only added the product images to the search results. The changes suggested by kashalo worked better for me, but could be improved a little bit.

Comment: Ur welcome. Can you please provide perhaps a link to the page to take a look. As you say the items are now shown in one single column, may be you can force woocommerce to show more items in a single row. take a look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work. I'm not able to post a URL at the moment, because the page is running in maintenance-mode at the moment and is not supposed to be public at the moment

Comment: I understand. Its quit difficult to figure out css modifications without the source page because i/we must see the css derived from theme and test inline modifications to reach the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to modify the way search is handled by Wordpress.
This can easily be done by adding an "action", add the below code to your `functions.php` file.

```
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('product'));
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

This will then make the search page only show products. It's worth noting that you can add other post types back in via the `array` in this line: `$query->set('post_type',array('product'));`.

Comment: I can also restrict the search results to products only in the "Ivory Search" plugin, but the problem of the way the results are displayed remains.

Comment: @TorbenWiesbach It looks your search results page is styled differently to your product/archive page. Try copy/pasting the contents of your products archive to the search results template file.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I have tried out your suggestion too, but it only worked partly. I have also added an image of the results to the main post.